# Powershell passing mandatory dynamic type variable to function

Tags: powershell, variable-declaration, function-declaration, powershell-cmdlet

I am implementing a function in Powershell which will perform REST calls. One of the parameters may differ in contents, depending on given scenarios. For instance, the `body` of the `REST` call may be a string or a hash table. How do you implement this within the `CmdletBinding()` declaration?

For instance

```
Function doRESTcall(){
[CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [Hashtable]$headers
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [???????]$body # what type here??
        )
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To declare parameters where *any type is allowed* you can either not type-constrain the parameter at all or use type constraint `[object]` ([System.Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0)), by doing so, no type conversion will be needed, since all objects in PowerShell inherit from this type.

It's worth mentioning that *unconstrained* parameters will allow `$null` as argument, to avoid this, [`[ValidateNotNull()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#validatenotnull-validation-attribute) and / or [`[parameter(Mandatory)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#mandatory-argument) can be used.

```
function Test-Type {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        [object]$Value
    )

    process
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Type     = $Value.GetType().FullName
            IsObject = $Value -is [object]
        }
    }
}
```

```
PS /> 1, 'foo', (Get-Date) | Test-Type

Type            IsObject
----            --------
System.Int32        True
System.String       True
System.DateTime     True
```

Comment: Glad to hear you think so. Same to you!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to tackel this is to create a [**ParameterSet**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets):

```
Function doRESTcall(){
    [CmdletBinding()]
            param (
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName = 'StringBody', Position = 0)]
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName = 'HashBody', Position = 0)]
                [Hashtable]$headers,
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName = 'StringBody', Position = 1)]
                [String]$Stringbody,
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName = 'HashBody', Position = 1)]
                [Hashtable]$Hashbody
            )
    Write-Host 'Parameter set:' $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
    Write-Host 'StringBody:' $StringBody
    Write-Host 'HashBody:' $HashBody
}
```

**`doRESTcall -?`**

```
NAME
    doRESTcall

SYNTAX
    doRESTcall [-headers] <hashtable> [-Hashbody] <hashtable> [<CommonParameters>]

    doRESTcall [-headers] <hashtable> [-Stringbody] <string> [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

**`doRESTcall @{a = 1} 'Test'`**

```
Parameter set: StringBody
StringBody: Test
HashBody:
```

**Note:** to accept a larger variety of dictionaries (like `[Ordered]`), I would use a `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]` (rather than `[Hashtable]`) type for the concerned parameters.